# Whats the difference between saving content at document directory or temp folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to save multipel photos in my application, so that application run in background.
So what is the main difference between saving photos in doc dir or temp path.

And suggest me which is best way to save photos

1. Document Dir
2. Temp Folder
3. `NSUserDefaults`

Thanks in advance

Comment: How long do you want to keep the photos for?

Comment: If photos can be downloaded again should be in `NSCachesDirectory`, saving photos in `NSDocumentsDirectory` may cause your app to be rejected, as stuff in there may be synced to device

Comment: i want to run my application even we are not in internet area, mean download the image when we are in internet area, and also show images in not internet area.

Comment: why app will rejected ?

Comment: @Rajneesh071, It is against Apple's data storage guidelines, check this answer for better understanding  stackoverflow.com/a/7963969/5228

Comment: After downloading the Images write the Images in Documents directory and check whether you have internet or not. If you have internet then take the images from your server or else take the images from documents directory

Comment: @iNoob then where to save my photos?

Comment: @Rajneesh071, If it is an image where user manipulate from your app like adding effects etc. then storing in documents directory maybe fine. But if they are images from internet on which user is not going to do any manipulation i'm guessing should be saved in cache directory. It won't be deleted instantly so you won't have to redownload every time. But you need to do a check if images are present and need for redownload.

Comment: hi, is there any way to save photos in phone memory, but no one can use images instead of application

Answer (score 4):

Here is a reference: [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

Temp folder:

> Use this directory to write temporary files that do not need to
>   persist between launches of your app. Your app should remove files
>   from this directory when it determines they are no longer needed. (The
>   system may also purge lingering files from this directory when your
>   app is not running.)

Documents folder:

> Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data
>   files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app,
>   such as user-generated content.

Usually, I put files in temporary folder only when I cache something and I don't care if these files will be deleted. If I want to be sure these files should live long life, I put them to documents folder.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is the path: `<sandbox>/Documents` or `<sandbox>/tmp`.

Some more differences:

1. The `Documents` directory can be accessed via iTunes if your app has file sharing enabled.
2. The contents of the `tmp` directory is volatile, the OS is free to purge it in order to save space.

About `NSUserDefaults`: that's something completely different, it's a mechanism which stores app-specific configuration data in property lists, I can't imagine how and/or why you would use it for storing images.

Comment: i want to run my application even we are not in internet area, mean download the image when we are in internet area, and also show images in not internet area.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Nice, and what does this have to do with the question or the answer?

Comment: @Rajneesh071, in this case you should use documents folder.

Comment: @Vova but iNoob saying that apple will reject my app if i will save photos in doc dir.

Comment: @Rajneesh071, are these photos produced by your app? If yes — it is user-generated content and it can be stored in "documents". If these photos are downloaded from the Internet, then you may want consider "Cache" folder.

Comment: this are internet downloaded images, but i want to run application without internet too, thats y i want to save them ...

Comment: and if i will save them in cache folder then app will deleted it automatically

Comment: hi, is there any way to save photos in phone memory (not in application sandbox), and no one can use images instead of application –

Comment: mean i want to save photos in phone memory using my application not in photoLibrary... so only my app can access this.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Well, the Documents directory does the trick, doesn't it?